# Python not iterating over array with for loop

Tags: python

*Write a program that fills an array of 10 elements with random numbers from 1 to 10, and then swaps the first element with the second, the third with the fourth, and so on. Display the original and transformed array*

Here is my solution, but Python doesn't want to sort the array and it stays the same:

```
from random import randint

numbers = []
for i in range(10):
    numbers.append(randint(1, 10))
    
print(numbers)
a = 0

for a in range(10):
    numbers[-1], numbers[i] = numbers[i], numbers[-1]
    a = a + 2

print(numbers)
```

I have tried replacing elements with a loop by `numbers[a] = numbers[a+1]` , But I kept getting the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You can't manually iterate (`a = a + 2`) and do it with a for loop at the same time with the same variable. Either use a `while` loop or don't change your iteration variable inside the loop.

Comment: `range` has a third optional `step` argument (e.g. `range(0, 10, 2)`)

Comment: you iterate over a and don't use it, you just use the variable i which is just leftover from previous for loop

Comment: In your code `i = 9` when you hit the second loop so `numbers[-1], numbers[i] = numbers[i], numbers[-1]` is just swapping the last element with itself. It really makes no sense to use `i` in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things here:
*1:* as @bereal said, range() has a tird optional step argument, and I've never seen a better time to use it. Check out the documentation for `range()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

*2:* I see you reference `numbers[-1]` even though I think you mean `number[-i]`, it will still reference `numbers[-1]` on the first iteration, thereby giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the swap when its not an even number like this:

```
for a in range(10):
    if a % 2 == 1:
        tempNumber = numbers[a]
        numbers[a] = numbers[a-1]
        numbers[a-1] = tempNumber
```

And then you will have

First output:

```
[9, 7, 4, 7, 4, 3, 1, 9, 9, 9]
```

Final output:

```
[7, 9, 7, 4, 3, 4, 9, 1, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Why not just `for a in range(1, 10, 2):` and avoid the check?

Comment: Also, as the OP already used in the question, a swap in Python can be done with one line without temp variables `numbers[a-1], numbers[a] = numbers[a], numbers[a-1]`

Comment: actually way better with for a in range(1, 10, 2) as you said @Tomerikoo, I just followed the question and forgot about steps in the for loop, my bad.